# Check if a quosure contains a string

Tags: r, rlang

I have a function that used to accept unquoted input back when I was first learning about NSE and now I hate it in this use case. I want to force the function to only take a string, but provide a clear error message on what happened back to the user.

My problem is testing for what type of input is being passed along. I can use `rlang::quo_is_symbol(rlang::enquo(str_x))`, but this will fail when chaining together multiple functions. Here is my cut at a reprex.

```r
fun1 <- function(str_x) {
  depr_str_x(str_x)
  paste("this is x", str_x)
}

depr_str_x <- function(str_x) {
  
  if (rlang::quo_is_symbol(rlang::enquo(str_x))) {
    stop("this is a clear error message to the user")
  }
  
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

So when I run this, I get what I want.

```r
depr_str_x("test") # nothing (which I want)
depr_str_x(test)   # my custom error (which I want)
```

But when I run this, I get the error both times. How do I get it to recognize that `"test"` being passed through is a string? I have also tried `rlang::is_scalar_character()` but that fails for the symbol case. I was hoping there was a quick and easy way to do this without forcing evaluation and seeing if it fails or something.

```r
fun1("test")       # my custom error (which I don't want)
fun1(test)         # my custom error (which I want)
```

Further, this should work when the function gets used inside of other functions. This is where I keep running into problems with my approaches.

```r
fun2 <- function(str_x) fun1(str_x)

fun2("test")       # my custom error (which I don't want)
fun2(test)         # my custom error (which I want)
```

Comment: I don't want unquoted to work. I explicitly am trying to block that. That is how I had it before but I want to remove that capability because it is resulting in bad practice as this package gets used in other packages. It is causing other errors to occur. But I don't want to just remove it without showing a clear error.

Comment: I updated the post, but I just wonder whether it matters about the prefix part in Error message is `depr_str_x(!!str_x)` instead of `depr_str_x(test)`

Comment: No, I think you get what I am going after. That would be fine. I am processing your update.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working (but am not sure this won't have bugs creeping up) by crudely trapping the error `object 'x' not found`. I am leaving the question open and welcome better solutions.

```r
depr_str_x <- function(str_x) {
  
  is_valid <- tryCatch(rlang::is_scalar_character(str_x),
                     error = function(e) {
                       if (grepl("not found", e, fixed = TRUE)) {
                         return(FALSE)
                       } else {
                         stop(e)
                       }
                     })
  
  if (!is_valid)
    stop("this is a clear error message to the user")
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSE arguments and arguments that may or may not be NSE require [quasiquotation](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html) to be properly passed from one function to the next. The most straightforward way is to use `{{`:

```
fun1 <- function(str_x) {
  depr_str_x({{str_x}})                   # <-- Note the {{ operator
  paste("this is x", str_x)
}

fun1("test")   # [1] "this is x test"
fun1(test)     # Error in depr_str_x({ : this is a clear error message to the user
```

The same holds for `fun2`:

```
fun2 <- function(str_x) fun1({{str_x}})   # <---- Ditto on {{

fun2("test")   # [1] "this is x test"
fun2(test)     # Error in depr_str_x({ : this is a clear error message to the user
```

**EDIT:** Something to keep in mind is that by allowing arguments that may or may not be NSE, you are creating ambiguity. Consider,

```
test <- "This is a string"
fun2(test)                    # What should happen here?
```

My general advice for your situation would be to drop NSE support altogether and document the change. NSE input will then fail automatically, but with an error that says "Variable test not found", which should be enough for most users to figure what the issue is.

Comment: My question is literally due to me doing what you recommend in the last paragraph :). I am dropping NSE support and trying to find a quick and easy way to add in a function to other functions that throws a `deprecation_stop()` if it is not a scalar character. My problem was the whole object not found for the case of a NSE input being passed along from various other functions.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding the use case, but "object not found" is the expected behavior for a function that doesn't support NSE. Adding `deprecation_stop()` is not a true drop of NSE, because it requires NSE to trigger it, which implies that the function calling `deprecation_stop()` has to accept unevaluated arguments. Basically, your two options are to 1) let "object not found" happen, or 2) use `{{` to pass unevaluated arguments around, so they reach `deprecation_stop()`.

Comment: You actually nailed my problem. I am basically trying figure out of if I have a valid object (of type character) captured within a quosure. It it isn't, it's likely because the user entered in an unquoted object, and I want to tell them clearly what to do. So what I did as a work around was trapped the "object not found" error and replaced it with another error of my choice. Maybe that is just what has to be done? I appreciate your thoughts on this. I was hoping I could just "know" that it was never a string, but it seems I would have to trace the entire call stack at that point.